# Finding Mean value program. Variable declaration and inputs

Tags: c

The program always prompts me to give one more input, if I declare 3 vars asks 4 inputs etc... The catch here is that if i put another variable inside the program, it always prompts me to input one more from the number i declared at the first place.
It DOES show the average correctly, but always asks me to give one more input which i think program doesnt even count and probably its the last input it asks me, but its there!

```
//Variable declaration.
int math,pro,net;                                            
int average;     

//ask user to give 3 grades.
printf("Give me your grades from your last semester\n"); 

//prompt user.
scanf("%d\n %d\n %d\n",&math,&pro,&net);

// simple average.
average = (math+pro+net)/3; 

// show average.
printf("Your average is :%d\n\n",average);
```

Comment: Pull the newlines from your format string unless you *really* want them. (and while you're at it. Make sure `scanf` returned 3 before assuming it did).

Comment: you cannot print anything using scanf();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
scanf("%d\n %d\n %d\n",&math,&pro,&net);
```

to

```
scanf("%d %d %d",&math,&pro,&net);
```

however, the real problem was the last newline character in your scanf format. scanf would keep on eating up whitespace character and won't terminate. however, if you send to stdin an EOF sign (hit ctrl+d on linux) the average will be computed with 3 variables specified.

note that newlines are treated by scanf same as other whitespace characters.

Comment: everyone makes mistakes:)

Answer (score 1):

Its because extra "\n" at the end of the scanf function. You can either Do the following code:

`scanf("%d %d %d",&math,&pro,&net);`

or if you want to follow your coding standard then write:

```
scanf("%d\n %d\n %d",&math,&pro,&net);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also note that your calculation is in itegers. If your grades are in the continental range (i.e. 1..5) you probably want to `float average = (math+pro+net)/3.; printf("Your average is :%f\n\n",average);` to avoid the loss of the fractional part od the result.